# Sorting my Trips From Most likes to Least likes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Im having trouble  successfully sorting  my trips from most amount of likes to least amount of likes. I want to use sort(). ive started with trying to pass the props from the store to myTrip component. what i have at the moment in mytrips is im using map to list all of the trips that i have at the moment. This is a react redux app. Here is my code.

```
 

  import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import  TripCard from './TripCard.js'

const MyTrips = props => {
  const tripCards = props.trips.length > 0 ?
      props.trips.map(t => <TripCard trip={t} key={t.id}/>) : null
    

      

  return (
      
      tripcards


  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    trips: state.myTrips,
    likes: state.mytrips
    
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyTrips)


**MyTrips Reducer**

const initialState = []

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
  case "SET_MY_TRIPS":
    return action.trips
  case "ADD_TRIP":
    return state.concat(action.trip)
  case "UPDATE_TRIP":
    return state.map(trip => trip.id === action.trip.id ? action.trip : trip)
  case "DELETE_TRIP":
    return state.filter(trip => trip.id === action.tripId ? false : true)
  case "CLEAR_TRIPS":
    return initialState
  default:
    return state
}
}

**AddTripLike Action**

  export const addTripLike = (tripData,history) => {
return dispatch => {
const sendableTripData = {
  likes: tripData.likes
}

return fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/v1/trips/${tripData.tripId}/add_likes`, {
  credentials: "include",
  method: "PATCH",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(sendableTripData)
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(resp => {
  if (resp.error) {
    alert(resp.error)
  } else {
    //window.location.reload();
    console.log(resp.data)
    dispatch(updateTripSuccess(resp.data))
    history.push(`/trips/${resp.data.id}`)

  }
})
.catch(console.log)  
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case it would look like this:

```
trips.sort((a, b) => {
  b.likes - a.likes
}
```

To give you a quick overview of how it works:

When you use (b - a), it will either

1. return a value bigger than 0 which is interpreted as true.
2. return a value of zero which will be interpreted as false.
3. Get a negative value which is also interpreted as false.

This way all values will be sorted in descending order.
If you want to learn more, check out the sort documentation.

Another useful overview:

https://www.javascripttutorial.net/array/javascript-sort-an-array-of-objects/